# I am facing mod_pagespeed image rename issue while page optimization

Tags: mod-pagespeed

i have mod_pagespeed implemented on my website. but it optimizes the images it changes the name to a very long file name. Can this hurt search engine optimization because i am getting good traffic from image search.

Can this image rename prevented in configuration file some where. i am using latest version of page speed (1.8...)

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My server is currently running PageSpeed version 1.8.31.4-4056. In our pagespeed.conf file, I see the following entry:

```
# Many filters modify the URLs of resources in HTML files. This is typically
# harmless but pages whose Javascript expects to read or modify the original
# URLs may break. The following parameters prevent filters from modifying
# URLs of their respective types.
#
# ModPagespeedJsPreserveURLs on
# ModPagespeedImagePreserveURLs on
# ModPagespeedCssPreserveURLs on
```

Looks like if you uncomment the last three lines, the URLs will be preserved. You'll then have to restart Apache.

I found some documentation about the settings here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters#preserveurls

Unfortunately, preserving URLs disables some other useful features.